# Laplace Transform of $t^2$ , for $t\ge1$ .

Tags: laplace-transform

$$f(t) = t^2 , t>=1$$
$$f(t) = 0, 0<t<1$$
what is the laplace transform of $f(t)$,
It is solved In my sheet as

$$t^2 = (t-1)^2 + 2t -1  $$
$$ L(f(t)) = e^{-s} L(t^2 +2t +1) = e^{-s}(2/s^3 + 2/s^2 + 1/s) $$

why it does not use the simple rule $L(t^n)=n!/s^{n+1}$

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $t^2H(t-1)$?

Comment: You appear to mean $t^2 H(t-1)$ where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. This will be equal to *zero* on $[0,1)$ and then equal to $t^2$ after that. The Laplace transform "sees" this difference on $[0,1)$.

Comment: Yes, in the range [0,1) it is zero.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(t)=t^2H(t-1)=\left[(t-1)^2+2(t-1)+1\right]H(t-1)$$
$$\mathcal L \{f(t)\}=\mathcal L \left\{\left[(t-1)^2+2(t-1)+1\right]H(t-1)\right\}=\mathrm e^{-s}\left[\frac{2}{s^3}+2\cdot\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{1}{s}\right]$$